# ckeditor ckfinder integration in php in IISv5.1 server

Tags: php, iis, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm trying to upload images. but the folder is creating in wwwroot place. i want to upload the image in 'uploads' folders. By the way here is IIS V5.1.!

```
                             ckeditor
wwwroot-->ckeditor_ckfinder-->
                             ckfinder
                             uploads
                             index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. You must give `uploads` file permission perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

Change baseDir / baseUrl settings in the server side configuration file to point to the uploads folder.

Comment: I used it . `$baseUrl = "C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/ckeditor_ckfinder/ckfinder/userfiles/";` But it shows an error message. **Folder not found. Please refresh and try again.** By the way my PHP version is 5.2.1. here my server is IIS 5.1. If I write `/upload/` in `$baseUrl` it shows me same error message. And If I write `upload/` then it make a folder out of wwwroot. I didn't change in `$baseDir`.

Comment: The `$baseUrl` you provided is perfect... but for `$baseDir` (which should contain the absolute path on the server). So set the same value, but for `$baseDir`. `$baseUrl` should be set to something around `/ckeditor_ckfinder/ckfinder/userfiles/` if I correctly understood your setup.

Comment: It makes the folder in C drive. But I need it into `userfiles` folder. Is here any change at JS? `filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&currentFolder=/upload/'`. And thank you so much for reply.

Comment: Send your configuration file that you believe is valid to the email shown here: http://cksource.com/contact Explain as good as you can where exactly files should be stored on the server and what URL to these files should be.

Comment: I sent it. Please check it.

Comment: Submitted ID is 13285. Please check this mail as far as possible.